# C++ use of undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

I know there's a lot of different threads with this similar issue but I've gone through a number of them and have fixed any of the possible issues that may be resulting in this error but I keep getting it.

I'm trying to test some of functions in my class file but whenever I try calling them I get that error.

Here's one for example.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Graph.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Graph graph;
    newState();
    return 0;
}
```

Graph.h (I know I shouldn't be using namespace here but I'm still doing it for now)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Graph{
public:
    Graph();
    Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N);
    void printGraph(Graph const &graph, int N);
    // print adjacency list representation of graph

    void createTree(GraphNode *root, int state[]);

    void newState();

private:
    int states = 8;
    int initialState[8];
    int nextState[8];

};
```

Graph.cpp

```
#include "Graph.h"
void Graph::newState(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 4 + 1;
    cout << random;
};
```

I feel like I'm trying to do the bare minimum but it just does not want to work. Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: graph.newState();

Comment: Oh. My. God. *facedesk* Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newState` is not a free-standing function. It is a non-static member function of `Graph` class. Which means, it must be called on an instance of `Graph`.  What you probably meant to do is:

```
Graph graph;
graph.newState();
```